# How to Extract mathjax code from the web page

Tags: latex, mathjax

I want to extract Mathjax code from a web page
It should be noted that the right click display of the code has been disabled
Now what can I do to see the Mathjax codes?
Thanks for the time. :)

Comment: if you can't right click you may type in the url bar **view-source:www.website.com** and copy/paste any part of the source :)

Comment: I haven't tested it yet, but maybe you should take a look to this tool which looks awesome : https://itsfoss.com/mathpix/

Answer (score 2):

Go to the browser console and type

```
MathJax.Hub.Config({showMathMenu: true})
```

(and press RETURN).  This will enable the math menu again to that you can get access to the Show Math As menu items.

Comment: If MathJax is undefined, it may be that the content is in an iframe and MathJax has been loaded there.  Most browsers have a mechanism for attaching to the iframe and issuing the commands there, but it varied by browser.  It may also be that the page has pre-rendered the math on the server, and that MathJax is not present in the browser.  In that case, you will not be able to access the menu.  If you link to the website in question, we can check it out.

Comment: Yes, I checked that I've used the iframe tag. If you can send your email, I will send you the site and the information you need to log in to your site.